# ImageMagic What do Coordinates stand for

Tags: php, math, imagemagick, coordinates

I want to create an rectangle but I do now know what the coordinates

> x0,y0 x1,y1

in imagemagic stand for.

Like this?

```
x1_________y1
|         |
|         |
|_________|
x0         y0
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.rectangle.php#refsect1-imagickdraw.rectangle-parameters

Comment: Your diagram needs two values at each vertex.

Comment: could you show me please?

Answer (score 2):

Take the following example where `25,25` is `x0,y0`, and `175,175` is `x1,y1`...

```
convert -size 200x200 xc:white \
        -fill white -stroke red -strokewidth 4 \
        -draw 'rectangle 25,25,175,175' out.png
```

[image: x0,y0,x1,y1]

It's a basic coordinate system. You only need to provide two x/y points to determine where the rectangle will be drawn.

See [Primitive Draw Commands](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#primitives), and [Magick Vector Graphics](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php) docs & examples.

Comment: @TruthSerum Disagree. Only 2 points are defined (as per this diagram) where as yours shows 4 sets of coords, which will only serve to confuse.

Comment: But four coordinates defines a rectangle. If you substitute values for the variables in my diagram, that is what you get. If you substitute values into your diagram, you get a line. Additionally, your diagram appears to show the top-left as the origin, which is not correct.

Comment: @TruthSerum, why the down vote? The [source code](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/draw.c#L5778) draws based on delta between points. The "origin" is subjective to the image format.

Comment: From the imagemagick website: "A rectangle primitive is specified by the pair of points at the upper left and lower right corners". If you were drawing a polyline you would need all four co ordinates. Note the link to the php page is for Imagick the API and not Imagemagick via the command.

Answer (score -1):

Is this really a question? You didn't even bother to read the top of it's php.net page?
http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.rectangle.php

Comment: [coordinate](http://www.webquest.hawaii.edu/kahihi/mathdictionary/images/coordinate.png)  Where 0,0 is the bottom left corner of the image.